Plot a path in a very large 2D matrix using Matplotlib
I want to plot a path in a very large (e.g. 500K x 500K) 2D matrix. My current approach is creating an uint8 np array (for space-saving reasons, as I only have 4 possible values) and plotting it with plt.imshow(). The problem is that this strategy is very memory demanding, and fails for very large matrices. Example code of my current approach:
xlen = 100000
ylen = 100000
m = np.zeros(xlen, ylen, dtype=np.uint8)

# Update some points of the matrix using my logic, this is just an example
for x in range(xlen):
    m[x][x] = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30))
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
cmap.set_under(color='white')
ax.imshow(m, vmin=0.1, vmax=4, cmap=cmap)

Is there a way to start with a very large "blank" imshow (or equivalent), and only update specific coordinates? Or would it be better to use an image manipulation library like PIL?

It would be helpful if you'd further detail the use case. Maybe you can draw lines or other shapes on a canvas, without intermediate storage in a 2d array?

Whatever the method, PIL, or anything, if you use image, you gonna need a 500k×500k image in memory at some point, that is 250 Gb
We could try some hack, such as mapping the memory from a file, or trying some generator.
Something like
class MyFakeImage():
    def __len__(self):
        return 500000

    def __getitem__(self, y):
        # return a 500000 array according to your logic
        return [1 if x==y else 0 for x in range(500000)]

But, that is probably not the good solution. And even if you avoided created an actual 500k×500k image, matplotlib will create one internally, that will use at least 250 Gb.
The correct solution seems simpler to me. Your path is apparently made of a set of points. Why not simply use plt.scatter to draw those points ?
